# Deep Copying a generic LinkedList in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that deep copies my linked list. In my get(index) method I am creating a new Node. Still this isn't working but it's passing the reference.

```
        SLinkedList<E> newLinkedList=new SLinkedList<E>();

        for(int i=0;i<size();i++)
        {
        newLinkedList.addLast(get(i));
        }
        return newLinkedList;
    }
```

Comment: each item need to be copied - cloned (eigher by use and implement of Clone interface eighter by use of copy constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of E type need to be deep copied

Deep copy, meaning that fields are dereferenced: rather than references to objects being copied, new copy objects are created for any referenced objects, and references to these placed in copy. The result is different from the result a shallow copy gives in that the objects referenced by the copy are distinct from those referenced by origin, and independent.

You can do it either:

- by **implement a Cloneable interface** (as a marker) and **override clone method**
- or by use of **copy constructor**

ad 2)

```
    // example class 
    class E {

       // exampe field 
       private B someField; 

       // copy constructor 
       public E(E origin) {
           // deep copy item field here 
           somefield = origin != null 
                        ? new B(origin.someField)
                        : null;
       }
    }
```

ad 1)  override & implement clone mehod

```
    /**
     * Creates and returns a copy of this object.  The precise meaning
     * of "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The general
     * intent is that, for any object {@code x}, the expression:
     * <blockquote>
     * <pre>
     * x.clone() != x</pre></blockquote>
     * will be true, and that the expression:
     * <blockquote>
     * <pre>
     * x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()</pre></blockquote>
     * will be {@code true}, but these are not absolute requirements.
     * While it is typically the case that:
     * <blockquote>
     * <pre>
     * x.clone().equals(x)</pre></blockquote>
     * will be {@code true}, this is not an absolute requirement.
     * <p>
     * By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling
     * {@code super.clone}.  If a class and all of its superclasses (except
     * {@code Object}) obey this convention, it will be the case that
     * {@code x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()}.
     * <p>
     * By convention, the object returned by this method should be independent
     * of this object (which is being cloned).  To achieve this independence,
     * it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the object returned
     * by {@code super.clone} before returning it.  Typically, this means
     * copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep structure"
     * of the object being cloned and replacing the references to these
     * objects with references to the copies.  If a class contains only
     * primitive fields or references to immutable objects, then it is usually
     * the case that no fields in the object returned by {@code super.clone}
     * need to be modified.
     * <p>
     * The method {@code clone} for class {@code Object} performs a
     * specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does
     * not implement the interface {@code Cloneable}, then a
     * {@code CloneNotSupportedException} is thrown. Note that all arrays
     * are considered to implement the interface {@code Cloneable} and that
     * the return type of the {@code clone} method of an array type {@code T[]}
     * is {@code T[]} where T is any reference or primitive type.
     * Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this
     * object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of
     * the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the
     * contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method
     * performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.
     * <p>
     * The class {@code Object} does not itself implement the interface
     * {@code Cloneable}, so calling the {@code clone} method on an object
     * whose class is {@code Object} will result in throwing an
     * exception at run time.
     *
     * @return a clone of this instance.
     * @throws CloneNotSupportedException if the object's class does not
     *                                    support the {@code Cloneable} interface. Subclasses
     *                                    that override the {@code clone} method can also
     *                                    throw this exception to indicate that an instance cannot
     *                                    be cloned.
     * @see Cloneable
     */
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
```

*I think there is no way to enforce usage of copy constructor with generics. Cloneable is the only option here - @Ivan*

firs of all OP didn't mention if E is generic type 
but... if it is how about?

```
interface Copyable<T> { 
   T copy(); 
}

final class Wrapped <E extends Copyable<E>> {

   private E theObject; 

   public Wrapped(E arg) { theObject = arg.copy(); }

   public void setObject(E arg) { theObject = arg.copy(); }

   public E getObject() { return theObject.copy(); }

   public boolean equals(Object other) { 
       if (other == null) return false; 
       if (! (other instanceof Wrapped))  return false; 
     return (this.theObject.equals(((Wrapped)other).theObject)); 
   } 
}
```

[GENERICS HOW TO COPY](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#How%20do%20I%20best%20implement%20the%20clone%20method%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type) – How do I best implement the clone method of a generic type?

KEEP IN MIND THAT COPY CONSTRUCTOR IS PREFERRED OVER CLONE METHOD :)

So with a little help from REFLECTION we could do something like this:

```
public static <E> E createCopy(E item) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    try {
       Class<?> clazz = item.getClass();
       Constructor<?> copyConstructor = clazz.getConstructor(clazz);
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       E copy = (E) copyConstructor.newInstance(item);
       return copy;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

**edit:** I ended up doing it recursively and it worked. C-flow

Maybe more JAVA less mess (not generic solution but when you know E is a concrete Type with deep clone method)?

```
    java.util.LinkedList<DeepCloneable> origin;
    java.util.LinkedList<DeepCloneable> copy = origin != null
            ? new java.util.LinkedList<>(origin.size())
            : null;
    java.util.Iterator<DeepCloneable> iterator = origin != null 
            ? origin.iterator()
            : null;
    while (iterator != null 
            && iterator.hasNext()) {
        DeepCloneable next = iterator.next();
        DeepCloneable dcCopy =  next.deepClone();
        copy.add(dcCopy);
    }
```

Comment: I think there is no way to enforce usage of copy constructor with generics. `Cloneable` is the only option here

Answer (score 0):

To make a deep copy, you need to know how to copy `E`.

Since you don't know what `E` is, you need to be told how to copy `E`, e.g. by accepting a `UnaryOperator<E>` to do the copy operation.

The following will show examples of how to do that using a standard `LinkedList`, but it is easily adaptable to your custom implementation.

```
public static <E> LinkedList<E> deepCopy(LinkedList<E> original, UnaryOperator<E> copyOperator) {
    LinkedList<E> newList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (E e : original)
        newList.add(copyOperator.apply(e));
    return newList;
}
```

A common way for an object to copyable, is for it to implement `Cloneable`:

```
class CloneableObject implements Cloneable {
    private String value;
    public CloneableObject(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public CloneableObject clone() {
        try {
            return (CloneableObject) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e.toString(), e); // cannot happen
        }
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
LinkedList<CloneableObject> cloneableList = /*...*/;
LinkedList<CloneableObject> cloneableCopy = deepCopy(cloneableList, CloneableObject::clone);
```

Another more generally accepted way is for the object to implement a copy-constructor:

```
class CopyableObject {
    private String value;
    public CopyableObject(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public CopyableObject(CopyableObject original) { // copy constructor
        this.value = original.value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
LinkedList<CopyableObject> copyableList = /*...*/;
LinkedList<CopyableObject> copyableCopy = deepCopy(copyableList, CopyableObject::new);
```

Of course, if the class doesn't implement a means of copying itself, you can always do it yourself:

```
class SimpleObject {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
LinkedList<SimpleObject> simpleList = /*...*/;
LinkedList<SimpleObject> simpleCopy = deepCopy(simpleList, o -> {
    SimpleObject copy = new SimpleObject();
    copy.setValue(o.getValue());
    return copy;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing it recursively and it worked.

```
    SLinkedList<E> newLinkedList=new SLinkedList<E>();
    SNode<E> cur=head;
    if(cur==null) {
    return newLinkedList;
    }
    while(cur!=null) {
    newLinkedList.addLast(cur.element.deepClone());
        cur=cur.next;   
    }
    return newLinkedList;
}
```

Comment: very unplesant - if you know concrete type - E which has deep clone method you could write it more JAVA :)  see edit